# cannot get sidebar and scroll bar to stop above image

Tags: css, styles, format, scrollbar, sidebar

i have an acitive events list sidebar that i need to have stop above this beta sticker. how can i get the scroll bar and events to end above the sticker and not go behind it ?

here is some of my code:

layout.cshtml:

```
           <div class="s-betaSticker" style="position: absolute; bottom:0"></div> 
           <div class="s-list-event s-eventbar col scroll-y" style="overflow:auto";>
           <div class="s-list-title s-title">
           Active Events
           <form action="@Url.Action("Details", "Event")" id="acform" class="s-search" >
            @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                    .Name("s-searchEvents")
                    .DataTextField("Name")
                    .Filter("contains")
                    .MinLength(2)
                    .Placeholder("Search events...")
                    .Events(e => e.Select("onACSelect"))
                    .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetEvents", "Event")))
                )
             </form>                             
              </div>

        <div class="s-content">
        @Html.Partial("_EventList", (IEnumerable<ArdentMC.Sentry.Data.Event>)ViewBag.EventList)
        </div>       
     </div>
     <div class="s-stream col scroll-y" id="s-eventStream">
    <div class="s-event-details"></div>
    <div class="s-stream-content"></div>
     </div>

         <div class="s-stream col scroll-y" id="s-eventStream">
            <div class="s-event-details"></div>
             <div class="s-stream-content"></div>
          </div>
   css:

          .s-betaSticker {
           width: 150px;
            height: 121px;
         position: absolute;
           left: 0;
           bottom: 0;
            background-image: url("../Images/beta.png");
           background-size: cover;
              /* In case size is reduced/increased */
                  }
```

Please any advice or feedback will be greatly appreciated, i have been trying to fix this for days and cant seem to get. thank you 
and here is a screen shot of the issue--
 [image: sidebar issue]

Comment: Can't you just set a height on the list?

Comment: I tried that but the beta image still overlaps the list. i think if I can somehow make a background div for the image that has the same size and colors as the list than that will work, i just dont no how to do that...

Comment: I was hoping that the black portion of the event list would still extend to the bottom of the page (but the scroll bar would end just above the Beta sticker)…is this possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible!... you need a wrapping div that streches 100% and then set height to the inner div that contains the list..

It would be great if you could create a http://www.jsbin.com for this!

Comment: thanks for the advice. so I will need to have css for my list, my image and for a wrapper, is that correct? ill see if i can figure it out and recreate it in that jsbin.com...thanks so much!

Comment: is it possible to add a footer to the sidebar that contains the image and that way when i resize the page it wont overlap the sidebar content? can anyone help me figure that out please and thank you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own problem. i was able to add a footer into the sidebar and add the image into the footer. i just used the same styling and background color as the list and it worked perfectly, no overlapping and it looks great 
[image: working screen shot of scroll bar and image not overlapping]